# Access denied for user 'localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES) In dual version Xampp and different port

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, port

I have an project before witch already done in xampp(php 5) oldest version 
Because of that i have to install two different version of xampp witch 
xampp(php7)

- apache with port 80 , 443
- mysql with port 3306

php5

- apache port 444,7777
- mysql port 3307

the problem is when i want connect the database with my old project with php5 its say 
`Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
the code it this

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db_kereta_api"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3307","$host","$username","$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>
```

[its the error and link i use in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewxOy.png)

Please help guys i dont know if there another configuration needed  to make it work
Thanks You

Comment: Your message says that is trying to connect with a user name of 'localhost'?!

Comment: oh yeah i think the hostname is 'localhost' so it actually hostname change it with ip address of the xampp with the port it use 
thank you for commend @NigelRen 
Sometimes we doesnt seen the little mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the mistake I just dont use to connect the webserver xampp with different port so the right answer is i duplicated the host name 
The right code is

```
<?php
$host="127.0.0.1:3307"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db_kereta_api"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

Sorry for Trouble